# Why does Thunderbird add "<a class="moz-txt-link-rfc2396E" href="http://schema.org">" to an html E-Mail?

Tags: html, email, microdata, thunderbird, json-ld

I have been searching for an answer to my question on google and on stackoverflow. Haven't found anything..

I try to send the following JSON-LDand Microdata schemas as an E-Mail to my Gmail-account:

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "Person",
 "name": "Max Mustermann",
 "affiliation": "Musterfirma",
 "telephone": "01234/56789",
 "url": "http://example.com/"
}
</script>
```

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
 <span itemprop="name">Max Mustermann</span>
 <span itemprop="affiliation">Musterfirma</span>
 <span itemprop="telephone">01234/56789</span>
 <a href="http://example.com/ itemprop="url">Website</a>
</div>
```

And when I am looking at the received E-mail it's always like this:

```js
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": <a class="moz-txt-link-rfc2396E" href="http://schema.org">"http://schema.org"</a>,
 "@type": "Person",
 "name": "Max Mustermann",
 "affiliation": "Musterfirma",
 "telephone": "01234/56789",
 "url": <a class="moz-txt-link-rfc2396E" href="http://example.com/">"http://example.com/"</a>
}
</script>
```

```html
    <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"> <span
        itemprop="name">Max Mustermann</span> <span
        itemprop="affiliation">Musterfirma</span> <span
        itemprop="telephone">01234/56789</span> <a
        href="http://example.com/%20itemprop=" url"="">Website</a>
    </div>
```

I add the html to a new E-Mail through the insert/HTML function in Thunderbird.
How can i change this behaviour of Thunderbird. Or can you recommend me another programm to send html E-Mails? 
I need the mails to be sent and received unchanged.. 
Thanks in advance!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case (JSON-LD): Thunderbird seems to auto-detect the URL and hyperlink it. [That’s a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=964024).

In the second case (Microdata): Thunderbird percent-encodes the URL in the `href` attribute. Why? Probably because you are missing a quotation mark: Instead of

```
<a href="http://example.com/ itemprop="url">Website</a>
```

it should be

```
<a href="http://example.com/" itemprop="url">Website</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, do you know any way to fix the bug (it says "verified fixed" in the bug report?) or any good alternative programm to send this JSON-LD?